# Flat map discriminated unions

Tags: c#

I'm using a lib off Github called [OneOf](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf).

Basically you have one type that can be one of many types, but in a statically safe way.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.
I have type `A<T1, T2, T3, T4>`, and type `B<T1, T2, T3>`, I'd like to "flapmap" type B into type A. Since type A can accept any single T from B, it should be possible.

The compiler forces me to extract each T from B before assigning it to A, as you can see by the silly `x => x` lambdas below.

I don't want to end up with some like `A<B<T1, T2, T3>, T4>` either.
So can anyone think of basically a SelectMany for these OneOf types?

```
using OneOf;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ScratchPad
{
    class Program
    {
        struct BadRequest { }
        struct Error { }
        struct NotFound { }

        static void Main(string[] arg)
        {
            string result = GetFile(@"c:\data\foo.txt").Match(
                text => text,
                badRequest => "filepath cannot be null",
                notFound => "filepath does not exist",
                error => "an error occurred"
            );

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        static OneOf<string, BadRequest, NotFound, Error> GetFile(string filepath)
        {
            OneOf<string, BadRequest, NotFound, Error> response = new BadRequest();

            if (filepath != null)
            {
                // How can I make the type from ReadText() automatically convert to the type of the response local variable, without having to write these silly lambda?
                response = ReadText(filepath).Match<OneOf<string, BadRequest, NotFound, Error>>(x => x, x => x, x => x); 
            }

            return response;
        }

        static OneOf<string, NotFound, Error> ReadText(string filepath)
        {
            OneOf<string, NotFound, Error> response = new NotFound();

            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(filepath))
                {
                    response = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                response = new Error();
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods could be a way.

An example, just out of my head, converting 3 to 4 types:

```
public static class OneOfExtensions
{
  public static OneOf<T1, T2, T3, T4> ConvertOneOf<T1, T2, T3, T4>(this OneOf<T1, T2, T3> oneOf)
  {
    return oneOf.Match<OneOf<T1, T2, T3, T4>>(x => x, x => x, x=> x);
  }

  public static OneOf<T1, T2, T3, T4> ConvertOneOf<T1, T2, T3, T4>(this OneOf<T1, T2, T4> oneOf)
  {
    return oneOf.Match<OneOf<T1, T2, T3, T4>>(x => x, x => x, x=> x);
  }

  public static OneOf<T1, T2, T3, T4> ConvertOneOf<T1, T2, T3, T4>(this OneOf<T1, T3, T4> oneOf)
  {
    return oneOf.Match<OneOf<T1, T2, T3, T4>>(x => x, x => x, x=> x);
  }

  public static OneOf<T1, T2, T3, T4> ConvertOneOf<T1, T2, T3, T4>(this OneOf<T2, T3, T4> oneOf)
  {
    return oneOf.Match<OneOf<T1, T2, T3, T4>>(x => x, x => x, x=> x);
  }
}
```

It's not particularly pretty, but it should keep your code relatively clean.